# Using an existing function's output as an object property

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object

I'm trying to use an existing function inside an object.

So far, all the answers I have seen focused on creating a **new** function inside an object, but I want to use an existing function inside an object. However, I am getting NaN as the output when I call the property name of the object.

The minimal reproducible code for my output is this:

```
    function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    bmi = weight/(height**2)
    return bmi;

}


var markDetails = {
    name:  "Mark",
    weight: 70,
    height: 175,
    bmi: bmiCalculator(this.weight,this.height),
    error: console.log(this.weight)

};



console.log(markDetails)
```

The problem seems to lie with the this.weight and this.height object definitions because they return NaN when I console.log(this.weight). But, I don't know exactly what went wrong

Comment: `this` isn't in the scope that you think it is. The easiest way to do this, especially if you expect to handle details for multiple people, is a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I followed it and have done it this way:
`function Person(name,weight,height,bmi){
    
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
    this.bmi = function bmiCalculator() {
        bmi = this.weight/(this.height**2)
        return bmi;
    }
}

var mark = new Person("Mark", 70, 1.75);
var john = new Person("John", 80, 1.75);` Is this the most elegant way to approach this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've mentioned in the comments you've gone with a constructor approach. A constructor just initializes an object. Because it is really just a function, `this` would be in the function's scope.

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    bmi = weight/(height**2)
    return bmi;
}

function Person(name, weight, height) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
    this.bmi = bmiCalculator(this.weight, this.height);
    // or this.bmi = bmiCalculator(weight, height)
}

var markDetails = new Person('Mark', 70, 175);
```

However, you don't really need `this` in this case. You can do the following:

```
function Person(name, weight, height) {
  return {
    name : name,
    weight: weight,
    height: height, 
    bmi : bmiCalculator(weight, height)
  }
}
```

This is the way I would personally do it. Getters are another good option, depending on how you want to interact with the object afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `this` in your objects is the window object, so when you do `this.weight` is `undefined`. So you need to change the scope of `this` to point to the current object, you can either do it within a `function` or `getter`.

use `getters`

```js
var johnDetails = {
    name:  "John",
    weight: 80,
    height: 175,
    get bmi() {
      return bmiCalculator(this.weight,this.height)
  }
};
```

and then access it like this

```js
johnDetails.bmi
```

use `function`

```js
var johnDetails = {
    name:  "John",
    weight: 80,
    height: 175,
    bmi() {
      return bmiCalculator(this.weight,this.height)
  }
};
```

and then access it like this

```js
johnDetails.bmi()
```